# Reusing JAX RS Client in multi-threaded environment (with resteasy)

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

According to the documentation,

> "Clients are heavy-weight objects that manage the client-side
>   communication infrastructure. Initialization as well as disposal of a
>   Client instance may be a rather expensive operation. It is therefore
>   advised to construct only a small number of Client instances in the
>   application. "

Ok, I'm trying to cache Client itself and WebTarget instances in a static variable, the someMethod() is invoked in multi-threaded environment:

```
private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
private static WebTarget webTarget = client.target("someBaseUrl");
...
public static String someMethod(String arg1, String arg2)
{
    WebTarget target = entrTarget.queryParam("arg1", arg1).queryParam("arg2", arg2);
    Response response = target.request().get();
    final String result = response.readEntity(String.class);
    response.close();
    return result;
}
```

But sometimes (not always) I'm get an exception:

> Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
>   Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

How can Client/WebTarget be reused/cached correctly? Is it possible with JAX RS Client API? Or I have to use some framework-specific features (resteasy/jersey) Could you provide some example or documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JAX-RS Client Thread Safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700798/is-jax-rs-client-thread-safe)

Answer (score 9):

Your implementation is not thread-safe. When two threads access `someMethod` at the same time they are sharing the same `Client` and one will try to make a second request while the first one is not finished.

You have two choices:

- Synchronize the access to the `Client` and `WebTarget` manually.
- Let the container manage concurrency by annotating the enclosing type with `@javax.ejb.Singleton` which guarantees thread safety. (see chapter 4.8.5 of the [EJB specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-pfd-spec.pdf))

If `someMethod` in a container managed environment I would use the second approach.

Comment: This is incorrect. `Client` is meant to be shared. That's why the client implementation class have volatile variables. `WebTarget` is not thread safe.

Comment: Could you please prove this with e.g. a link to the documentation?

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu: As discussed in the linked question [Is JAX-RS Client Thread Safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700798/is-jax-rs-client-thread-safe), unfortunately the spec does not require `Client` to be thread safe. In some implementations it is (e.g. in Jersey, I believe), in others it is not (e.g. Apache CXF).

Answer (score 8):

Since this issue is still open at the time of writing (version 3.0.X) [RESTEASY: deprecated Apache classes cleanup](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1357)

You can go deeper to use the newer, non-deprecated classes instead to create you resteasy client. You will also have more control over how you want the pool to be etc.

Here is what I did:

```
// This will create a threadsafe JAX-RS client using pooled connections.
// Per default this implementation will create no more than than 2
// concurrent connections per given route and no more 20 connections in
// total. (see javadoc of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm =
        new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient =
        HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine =
        new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(closeableHttpClient);
return new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).build();
```

Also **make sure you release the connection** after making a call. Calling response.close() will do that for you so probably put that in a finally block.

Answer (score 4):

First, do not reuse WebTarget. For simplicity, you can always create new WebTarget.

Second, if you're using Resteasy, you can add provided dependency for Resteasy client to your project. Example in Gradle:

```
    provided 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.0.14.Final'
```

Then, you can create your connection like this:

```
        ResteasyClientBuilder builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
        builder.connectionPoolSize(200);
```

There is no need to set maxPooledPerRoute, this is set automatically by RestEasy (can be found in RestEasyClientBuilder class source code).

When you set connectionPoolSize, you will no longer get error when Client is reused and you can happily re-use them all across the application. I've tried this solution on many projects and it actually works well. But when you deploy your application to a non-resteasy container (like Glassfish), your code won't work and you will have to use ClientBuilder class again.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is unfortunately not very clear about what can and can't be reused safely. When in doubt reuse nothing. However, if you're determined to minimize overhead you can safely reuse most objects depending on the methods called.

Starting with your code, here's some comments about what's happening:

```java
// (1) Store an instance of Client with its own configuration
private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
// (2) Store an instance of WebTarget with its own configuration (inherited from client)
private static WebTarget webTarget = client.target("someBaseUrl");
...
public static String someMethod(String arg1, String arg2)
{
    // (3) New instance of WebTarget (copy entrTarget config) with "arg1" param
    // (4) New instance of WebTarget (copy anonymous config) with "arg2" param
    WebTarget target = entrTarget.queryParam("arg1", arg1).queryParam("arg2", arg2);
    // (5) New instance of Invocation.Builder (copy target config)
    // (6) Invoke GET request with stored configuration
    Response response = target.request().get();
    final String result = response.readEntity(String.class);
    response.close();
    return result;
}
```

I commented on the code as-is but I'm guessing `(3)` should've referenced the static `webTarget` field.

A lot of objects are getting created here. Every time an object is created there's a new instance with its own copy of the configuration (so it won't affect its predecessors). In this particular case there should be no race conditions, but there are definitely ways in which this could go wrong.

If on or before `(3)` you had done something like this (assuming these are legitimate properties):

```java
WebTarget target = webTarget.property("foo", fooProperty).queryParam("arg1", arg1);
```

Then you would be altering the configuration of the static `webTarget` field and that could cause a race condition. There are many ways to alter the configuration from the static fields so you either need to guard them carefully or just not have them at all.

Also, be aware that pretty much every object that spawns from the original `client` will have a reference to it for the purpose of determining if the httpEngine has been closed. So unless you're trying to gracefully shutdown your application it's likely never a good idea to close the client.

And I found out all of this by digging through the source code because there's really no good reference.