# Reusing javax.ws.rs.client.Client

Tags: java, concurrency, resources, client

I have just ran a profiler on my code and I noticed that I spend a lot of time creating new clients using `ClientBuilder.newClient()`. This isn't that surprising as the documentation states that it is a heavy operation and that you should reuse the client if possible.

So I created a simple resource pool that should manage all of my Clients

```
public class SimpleClientResourcePool implements ResourcePool<Client> {
    private LinkedList<Client> pool = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public Optional get() {
        if(pool.isEmpty())
            return Optional.empty();
        return Optional.of(pool.getFirst());
    }

    @Override
    public void release(Client value) {
        pool.addLast(value);
    }
}
```

and I use it like this

```
    Client client = clientResourcePool.get().orElseGet(ClientBuilder::newClient);
    Response response = get(countryId, uri, client);

    try {
      ///random code
    } finally {
        response.close();
        clientResourcePool.release(client);
    }
```

When running locally with just me as a user I am not seeing any problems, but during load there seems to be a concurrency issue that I am not quite understanding.

I am getting an exception that seems to be based in this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is still allocated
        at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:266)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:217)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:313)
```

So is this not how you should reuse clients, or am I missing something obvious?

Closing the client seems to just result in other exceptions...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38343094/829571

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the issue your experiencing definitely related to your pool implementation. I actually see at least 3 problems in your code:

1. `SimpleClientResourcePool` is not a thread safe. Access to `pool` collection is not synchronized. In your case the `Queue` will also be better than `LinkedList`, so look at [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) provided by concurrent package.
2. You should withdraw `Client` object from the pool or move it to another collection of "used clients" depending on your needs before `release` is not called for it.
3. [Always do {} even around one-line if statements](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces). Code will not compile after automatic merge if someone in your team add another lines in that "if".

Applying such advises you can start from something like this:

```
public class SimpleClientResourcePool implements ResourcePool<Client> {
    private final Queue<Client> pool = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    @Override
    public Optional get() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(pool.poll());
    }

    @Override
    public void release(Client value) {
        pool.offer(value);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!