# How to close a proxied RESTEasy WebTarget

Tags: java, resteasy

Given the following RESTEasy snippet

```
UriBuilder FULL_PATH = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://127.0.0.1:8080/movies");

ResteasyClient client = (ResteasyClient)ClientBuilder.newClient();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(FULL_PATH);
MoviesResource proxy = target.proxy(MoviesResource.class);

Movie movie = proxy.movieById(someId);
```

I could/can/should close `WebTarget` or `Client` to free resources I allocated*.

However, what do I do if the creation of the proxy object and everything it depends on is handed off to a separate class like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private UriBuilder FULL_PATH = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://127.0.0.1:8080/movies");

    public MoviesResource getMoviesApi() {
        ResteasyClient client = (ResteasyClient)ClientBuilder.newClient();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(FULL_PATH);
        return target.proxy(MoviesResource.class);
    }
}

...

MoviesResource proxy = myFoo.getMoviesApi();
Movie movie = proxy.movieById(someId);
// A) how to clean up here?
```

How do I close the `WebTarget` or `Client` or their underlying resources? I can't get access to either of them through the proxied instance.
If I do *not* close them I get this dreaded warning

> RESTEASY004687: Closing a class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient43Engine instance for you. Please close clients yourself.

Hence, RESTEasy does clean up for me but that's of course not what I should rely on.

*there are discussions in a number of places eg. [Reusing JAX RS Client in multi-threaded environment (with resteasy)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33097230/131929) and [Is JAX-RS Client Thread Safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24700798/131929) about what is reusable and what not

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Comment: RedHat Quarkus ships with RESTEasy 4.7.7.

Comment: If you use the MP REST Client it extends `AutoCloseable` and allows the connection to be closed. That seems like a reasonable feature request in RESTEasy to me.

Comment: Hhh, that seems like a really valuable hint, thanks. Sorry, this is all so new to me that I first had to figure out what "MP" stands for. I checked the docs at https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.7.7.Final/userguide/html/MicroProfile_Rest_Client.html; currently analyzing how to potentially migrate our code base. What is e.g. the MP equivalent to this: `ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build().target(urlBuilder.build()).register(MyClientRequestFilter(appName, tokenProvider))`?

Comment: Something like this `RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .baseUri(urlBuilder.build())
        .register(yClientRequestFilter(appName, tokenProvider))
        .build(MoviesResource.class);`. You can also just inject it with CDI.

Comment: Thanks James. I was bit stuck on your earlier statement: "use the MP REST Client it extends `AutoCloseable`". Looking at `RestClientDelegateBean.destroy()` and the `CloseableClientTest` you recently added, isn't it more like "let the proxy interface extend `AutoCloseable` such that MP RESTEasy can close it"?

Comment: That is to say that I didn't find any code that would support the claim that MP `RestClientBuilder.build()` would automatically create an `AutoCloseable` proxy. Btw, I'm working with Quarkus which ships with its own almost-copy of that builder (`QuarkusRestClientBuilder`).

Comment: Yes, sorry that I was't clear. The MP spec requires the proxy extend `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable` if the interface does not already extend one of them https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-3.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-3.0.html#lifecycle. With CDI it automatically closes the proxy when the proxy is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the feedback from @james-r-perkins I eventually I arrived at the following (Kotlin) code:

```kotlin
final inline fun <reified T : AutoCloseable> createServiceProxy(
    serviceName: String
): T = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .baseUri(createServiceUriBuilder(serviceName).build())
    .register(MyClientRequestFilter(appName, tokenProvider))
    .build(T::class.java)
```

Contrary to my earlier comment both the [RESTEasy MP `RestClientBuilderImpl`](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-microprofile/blob/main/rest-client-base/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/microprofile/client/RestClientBuilderImpl.java#L385) and the [Quarkus `QuarkusRestClientBuilder`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/resteasy-classic/rest-client/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/restclient/runtime/QuarkusRestClientBuilder.java#L362) DO create proxies that *also* implement `Closeable` (which extends `AutoCloseable`). Just as James said...

However, we see value in enforcing that our client interfaces extend `AutoCloseable` directly. Sure, it's a few extra characters in the source code but on the plus-side it's type information the compiler can use to allow us to simplify code elsewhere. Hence, it's crucial here that the generics declaration is `T : AutoCloseable` rather than `T : Any`.